# Supremum and infimum of S

Tags: calculus

Let $$S=\left \lbrace \frac{n}{n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \right \rbrace.$$

With this said, I need to determine, with a proof, the supremum and infimum of $S$.

Please show all work and why.

Comment: Please avoid by saying "Please show all work and why"

Comment: `Please show all work and why` *You* please show your work and why not.

Comment: Where is your work, OP ?

Comment: Do you mean $n/(n+1)$? Because the set, as written is $S=\{2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is easy, can't post an image as of yet. I arranged the set into a strictly monotonically increasing sequence (that is 1/2, 2/3, 3/4,...and so on). Infimum is then, the first term itself, 1/2 (however if you include 0 in N, then infimum is 0). Since the sequence is monotonically increasing, showing that an upper bound exists (any number larger than 1 will do) is enough to show supremum exists and you can take limit of the terms n/(n+1), as n increases n/(n+1) tends to reach 1 and so supS is 1. Do avoid asking to show all the work. Also note that supS does not belong to S.

Answer (score 1):

The way I might approach this problem would be:
 
 1). Show that the sequence is strictly increasing. 
 2). Show that the limit of $\{s_n\}$ is 1 
 
Invoke the Monotone Convergence Theorem and properties of increasing sequences and you should be able to find the apparent $\inf$ and $\sup$.

Answer (score 1):

For the infimum, note that $n^2+2n+1>n^2+2n \implies(n+1)(n+1)>n(n+2)\implies\frac{n+1}{n+2}>\frac{n}{n+1}$, so each term is greater than the last. Therefore the infimum is the first term, as $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{n}{n+1}\forall n \in\mathbb{N}:n>1.$ For the supremum, due to the increasing nature of the sequence, there is no greatest term. Then any supremum will be a limit point of the series. It is obvious that $1$ is a limit point of the sequence. There cannot be a lesser limit point, as for any $\epsilon>0$ you can find a term $p$ such that $d(1,p)<\epsilon$. Specifically, $d(1,p)=1-p=1-\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}>\epsilon$ for any $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$. Therefore $\inf S=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sup S=1.$

For future reference, we have a few guidelines we tend to follow here to allow for better and clearer answers and more help for all. You should always give it a go yourself first, and then tell us what you've gotten so far. Even if you haven't gotten anything, just say so, that you have no clue how to advance, maybe just go through a couple check where some basic step take you; as long as you show you've at least tried and aren't just asking us to do a homework problem for you.

Comment: Yall I'm new to this whole thing, wasn't sure what to say in the question box. I put everything that I was asked on my homework. I wasn't fixin to say to y'all please show work, that's what my professor wrote. Nor do I know how to type it all mathematically correct. I got the proof to my understanin I was just checkin to see. Though I didn't use either of the ways listed. But thank yall for who posted their way of thinkin.